# VBA: Organizing a non rectangular range (edit)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of  "criss crossed" rows and columns that have been intersected:

```
Dim rows As Range
Set rows = Workbooks(insurance).Worksheets(from).Range(rngRows)

Dim cols As Range
Set cols = Workbooks(insurance).Worksheets(from).Range(rngCols)

Set Rng = Application.intersect(rows, cols)
```

I want to "collapse" the intersected cells so that there are no spaces between them. Thoughts?

Edit:
I need to pull data from say the intersection of say rngRows = "16:24,27:32,35:39" and rngCols = "E:E,I:I,M:M" and then essentially delete all the spaces between them or put it in an array. The problem is that Rng, doesn't order the range by column or row but into a bunch of broken up ranges so I can't loop through an entire columns first and then the next one.

Comment: You'll need to show a small example illustrating exactly what you mean by "collapse".  Do you mean you want to delete empty rows or columns on the sheet, or move data so that empty spaces get filled?

Comment: If you loop through each cell in `rngRows` you can check for intersect with `rngCols`, rather than trying to loop over `Rng`  Or vice-versa loop over `rngCols` and check against `rngRows`